# Swift UIbutton inside tableviewCell tp perform segue is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uibutton

I have a custom tableviewcell and I have button inside the cell when I click on the button the next viewcontroller does not show he content , but if I click on cell then clicking the button the next view controller showing the right content here is my code :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.label.text = numberArray[indexPath.row]
 cell.button.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.button.addTarget(self,action:#selector(TableViewController.someAction(sender:)),
                          for:.touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

here is my button action :

```
func someAction(sender : UIButton){

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)

}
```

and here is my segue function :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            {
                (segue.destination as! ViewController).number = numberArray[indexPath.row]

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you want? do you want to show the datail as a separate View Controller?

Comment: I want to segue to a new Viewcontroller with tappingon button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that in `prepare(for:sender:)` you are getting `indexPath` using `indexPathForSelectedRow` now if you directly click the button then cell with not selected what you need is to pass the `indexPath` of cell with `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`.

```
func someAction(sender:  UIButton) {
    let point = sender.superview?.convert(sender.center, to: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point!) {
        //pass indexPath as sender with performSegue
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Now in `prepare(for:sender:)` cast the `sender` to `indexPath` and you all good to go.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath
        {
            (segue.destination as! ViewController).number = numberArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** It is batter if you ignored to use `tag`.

Comment: what should I do instead of tag ?

Comment: @UncleJunior I have suggested you how to get `indexPath` without using `tag`. I have mentioned that because it is also recommended by Apple that don't relay on tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom cell and follow the steps:

- add action and outlet in the custom cell from the storyboard.
- After that, you have to add protocol methods in the custom cell(
  custom delegate method).
- and use these methods in your view controller. and add functionality
  for show detail.

Comment: Would you please add the code into your answer,  I am not sure how to do it, thanks

Comment: Second solution: You have to add tag as index path on the button and use this tag instead indexPathForSelectedRow

Comment: this is what I have done but it seems that when I click on the button it does not work I should select the cell first then click on the button to make it work, BTW thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


            if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {


                    (segue.destination as! ViewController).number = numberArray[sender.tag]

                }

        }
```

Comment: Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'tag'

Comment: Pass  uiButton through sender argument and try